# value not getting inserted in table

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to insert the userid into my table in a php file upload system.Every other value is properly getting inserted except the userid.Heres the code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
$id1 = $_GET['id'];


include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";


function savedata(){
global $_FILES, $_POST, $putItAt;
$sql = "INSERT INTO files (
ID ,
userid ,
Time ,
FileLocation ,
IP ,
Title
)
VALUES (
NULL ,'$id1' , UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) , '".mysql_real_escape_string($putItAt)."',   '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."'
);";
mysql_query($sql);


}
```

any way around this?

Comment: `userid` is an integer? Are you trying to insert a string? Did you check user input to avoid errors and sql-injection? Check if you get some error...

Comment: Is id a varchar or an int - Right now you are treating it as a varchar since you are wrapping it in single quotes

Comment: in the function savedata() you don't have any reference for $id1, you need to put it as a parameter.

Comment: Errrm, `$id1` isn't inserted, or `$userid` ?

Comment: Are you sure the value $id1 is accessible in the function savedata()? can you please echo the query $sql and check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to comments, i think the trouble is that `$id1` isn't accessable in `savedata()` function. So you need to declate `$id1` global inside function or use `$_GET['id']` in you sql-query, like `VALUES (NULL , " . $_GET['id'] . " , UNIX_TIMESTAMP( )`.

Answer (score 1):

Possible Problems:

**1.** I think problem is that  you are passing `$id1` as string in your SQL query but I think datatype of `userid` filed is `int` in your database structure.

Try something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO files (
ID ,
userid ,
Time ,
FileLocation ,
IP ,
Title
)
VALUES (
NULL , " . $id1 . " , UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) , '".mysql_real_escape_string($putItAt)."',   '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."'
);";
```

**2.** Also you need to check which `userid` you want to insert into database:

```
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
$id1 = $_GET['id'];
```

**3.** Also `print_r(  $_SESSION );` and `print_r( $_GET );` to check if required values exists in array.

**4.** Also read [Den's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9324221/149206) which I missed while reading your code.

So your function signature may be something like this:

```
function savedata( $id1 ) {
  ------
}
```

Pass `$id1` to `savedata` function while calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query. it may works for you.

$sql = "INSERT INTO files (`ID`,`userid`,`Time`,`FileLocation`,`IP`,`Title`)
VALUES (NULL ,'$id1' , UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) , '".mysql_real_escape_string($putItAt)."',   '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."'
)";

some times because of reserve keyword of mysql it will cause this kind of problem. so try to use  `  before and after or field name.